# Difference in output using for loop & while loop using settimeout function javascript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, while-loop, settimeout, let

I'm aware of the difference between the var & let variable declaration. I just executed the same piece of code using for loop & while loop. To my surprisingly I got the different output & I'm not able to differentiate the execution behavior difference between them.

I have attached 2 code snippets using While loop & For loop.

If anyone is aware of this then please help me.

```js
let i = 0;
while(i < 5) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(i)
  }, 1000);
  i++;
}
```

```js
for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(j)
  }, 1000);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58044285 - declare a block-scoped variable inside the loop with `while` so it can be accessed inside the timeout

Comment: @CertainPerformance That's a good turnaround, but I was more interested in getting know why is this kind of change in behavior. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Because in the `while` loop, there's only one binding of `i`, which has reached 5 after the loop ends. In the `for` loop, there are 5 separate bindings of `j`, one for each iteration block.